# Apple pay with Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay, firebase-extensions

I am having trouble with enabling Apple Pay on my Stripe checkouts. I have enabled it from the dashboard but it does not show up during checkout. Any reasons as to why? I am using one time payments with the firebase stripe extension. It works so far with card, but I would like to expand it to apple/google pay. Am I also using the stripe premade checkout dashboard.

[image]

Thanks!

I've tried enabling apple pay and configuring to my domain. I don't think configuring it to my domain matters as it opens the checkout session in stripe's domain.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this Stripe [page](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button) in Safari browser to check your Apple Pay readiness. If you can see an Apple Pay button, it means your browser is ready for Apple Pay, otherwise it means you haven't set up an active card in Safari, or you are in a country where Apple Pay is not supported.

If you can see Apple Pay button in this page, but not in your Checkout pages, you should reach out to [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) and they will help you investigate further.

Comment: The button showed up for me. I will contact stripe support to see what they have to say. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Apple pay only shows up on mac's safari browser and iPhone's safari browser.
it will not show on the windows